# How can I insert new rows in table 2 to table 1 comparing the ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know how I can insert new rows in my table 1 of table 2. The idea is that by comparing the two tables if in the second one you do not find the same ID in table 1 this inserts the new data in table 1.

This is the two table and the idea I want to do:

```
Tabla 1  
ID-Name-Surname  
1-Oriol-Molina

Tabla 2
ID-Name-Surname  
1-Oriol-Molina  
2-Ricard-Martin
```

And the result would be this:

```
Tabla 1  
ID-Name-Surname  
1-Oriol-Molina  
2-Ricard-Martin

Tabla 2
ID-Name-Surname  
1-Oriol-Molina  
2-Ricard-Martin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the database to enforce data integrity.  That is, if you don't want duplicate `id`s in the table, then declare a unique index/constraint:

```
create unique index unq_table1_id on table1(id);
```

Then, in MySQL, you can use `on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into table1 (id, name, surname)
    select id, name, surname
    from table2 
    on duplicate key update id = values(id);
```

The final statement is a no-op -- it does nothing except prevent an error.

The advantage of this approach is that the database will ensure that `id` is unique for *any* statement that inserts data into the table, not just this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`INSERT INTO .. SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) with `LEFT JOIN` and `IS NULL` check, to fetch only those rows from `Table2` which do no exist in `Table1`

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, Name, Surname)
SELECT t2.ID, t2.Name, t2.Surname 
FROM Table2 t2 
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
WHERE t1.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a left join

```
insert into table1 
  select id, name, surname from table2 left join table1 on table2.id=table1.id
  where table1.id is null
```